# Is there a way to submit a form on an element's #ajax?

Tags: forms, ajax

given a form like this:

```
function awesome_form() {

 $form['select'] = array(
     '#type' => 'select'
     '#options' => array(
        'hello' => t('Hello'),
        'good-bye' => t('Good Bye'),
     ),
     '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'awesome_ajax',
        'progress' => FALSE,
     ),
 );

 $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
 $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
   '#type' => 'submit',
   '#value' => t('Save'),
 );

 return $form;

}
```

I want the ajax callback on the select box to fire a submission.
So for instance, when someone selects "Hello" the form submits and when someone selects "Good Bye" the form submits.
Right now (with the code above), awesome_ajax() fires like it's supposed to, but I can't seem to get the form to submit (save the data in the database).

Also, I would like it if there wasn't a visible submit button on the page (as the submit button is unnecessary).

How would I do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You've not mentioned what your ajax callback is doing internal to it, but if all you want is to submit the form upon a change, you can do something like this in jQuery with no drupal involvement:

```
$('#edit-submit').hide();
$("#edit-field-FIELDNAME-0-value").live('change', function() {
  $('#edit-submit').click();
});
```

where `#edit-submit` is the id= in the form html of the submit input button and `#edit-field-FIELDNAME-0-value` is the id= of your select that you want the form submited upon change.  Throw this and the appropriate drupal behavior wrapper into a js file and you can drupal_add_js() it from your form hook.

ADDITION:

I suppose `$('#form-id').submit();` is better than `$('#edit-submit').click();` above where `#form-id` is the id= of your form.

Also, if you are running D6, you'll need the jQuery Update module installed.

Answer (score 0):

If there was no submit button there, I would normally make an ajax call when the selection field is changed, pass the data to a menu callback and had it's function do the saving to the database

```
$('select').change(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == 'selection 1') {
       $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '?q=modulename/save_data',
          data: 'data=' + $(this).text(),
          success: function() {
             // do other stuff..
          }
       });
  }
});
```

For the menu callback on my custom module, it would be like

```
function modulename_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['modulename/save_data'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'modulename_save_data',
      'access arguments' => array('administer nodes'),
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );

  return $items; // make sure to clear your drupal cache in order for this menu callback to work
}

function modulename_save_data() {
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    // do the rest here...
}
```